Horror movie with a couple who are attacked in a bar, then fed to zombies that come up from under the ground
There's a movie I am looking for; I can't remember when it came out. 
In the movie, a man and a woman go into a bar, the woman sits down and the man goes to the toilets. A group of drunk men try touching her and the woman behind the bar pulls a gun out and they all leave. The woman goes to check where the man is and when she goes into the toilet he's not there. She finds a small doorway that leads to a basement, and there finds the man in the cage.
Towards the end of the movie the fat woman from behind the bar hangs the people upside down on a post and sits and waits for zombies to come up from the ground and eat them. In the end they kill the woman.
Can anyone identify this film?

Pretty sure I know what you're after, but can you at least estimate the decade? (Recent? 90s? 70s?) The movie's country\language?
